# how to disable a button and change text when clicked

Tags: angular

I'm setting a text in a button when clicked, but it makes it so quick. In fact it changes it for half seconds and returns it to the old message....it doesn't disable it

I'm using this in my html

```
 <button mat-flat-button color="accent"
   (click)="cancelBuildingImage(element.buildId); setSaving($event.target, 'Canceling...')">
            Cancel Build
    </button>
```

and this in ts:

```
setSaving(element, text) {
    element.textContent = text;
    element.disabled = true;
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Don't directly manipulate DOM elements. Use the Angular features for rendering changes in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the text in a property or in your `element` variable.

Something like this:

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="accent" (click)="cancelBuildingImage(element.buildId); text = 'Cancelling...'">
     {{ text }}
</button>
```

```js
export class MyComponent {
    text = 'Cancel Build';
}
```